# local tangent approximation on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a smooth $d$-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with "bounded curvature" (i.e. positive reach). $A(p)$ is small neighborhood around $p\in\mathcal{M}$ and $\tilde{A}(p)$ is its projection to $T_p(\mathcal{M})$. Let $\mu$ be the $d-$dimensional Hausdorff measure. Can we show that $$\frac{\mu[A(p)]}{\mu[\tilde{A}(p)]}\rightarrow1,$$ uniformly in $p\in\mathcal{M}$ as the diameter of $A(p)$ tends to 0?